# How to change prompt in jailshell

Tags: linux, prompt

My ISP has switched to jailshell at some point, and now when I SSH in my prompt is always:

```
-jailshell-3.2$
```

I'd like it to be:

```
`pwd` $
```

Where do I configure this?  I seem to recall some kind of config file, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute:

`touch ~/.bashrc; echo 'PS1="\w $"' >> ~/.bashrc`

This will create the file `.bashrc` in your home directory if it doesn't already exist, and append `PS1="\w $"` to it.

The environment variable `PS1` defines your prompt, and the escape sequence `\w` translates to the current working directory (pwd).
A full list of escapes sequences can be found [here](http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/howtos/Bash-Prompt/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO-2.html#ss2.5).

To make the shell reflect the changes made in `.bashrc` without restarting the session, run `source ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: if I do `source ~/.bashrc` I get the prompt like you say, but it isn't doing that on login

Comment: oh wait i got it to work. since it is a login prompt i have to use `~/.bash_profile`, not `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad it worked :).

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK jailshell reads .bashrc 
so man bash is your friend

Answer (score 0):

~/.bash_profile - This works for hostgator PS1 prompt